# How to create and link image database with java code for android application processing

Tags: java, android, database, xampp, cbir

i am making an android application on CBIR i.e reverse image search for my final year project. I have started with developing an algorithm for the same in java using eclipse which is working properly. But its basing its search upon the images in the folders of computers. However in my case in the end i have to port my java code to android. So how will i make it possible to fetch images from my folder for processing on the android app.By searching on google i got an idea of using Xampp for the same but the php code is working to an extent but not storing the images in the phpmyadmin database. What is the most feasible way to do the same, i am stuck at image database part. Please help with the choice of software and methods for the same.